# How to use Current project Exception object in my Visual Studio c# Extension

Tags: c#, plugins, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions

I mean to say that I developed a visual studio C# extension and from this extension, I opened a c# project. In this project, I got an Exception, so now I want this Exception object or message to display in my Extension or use in it.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this method to call the projectITem c #.

```
itemPath = solution.GetProjectItemTemplate("ItemClass.zip", "CSharp");
fileExtension = ".cs";
```

If you have any doubt about the wizard extension you can access this site:

"[Use wizards with project templates](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/how-to-use-wizards-with-project-templates?view=vs-2017)"